# How to test if hbase is correctly running

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I just installed hbase on a EC2 server (I also have HDFS installed, it's working).
My problem is that I don't know how to check if my Hbase is correctly installed.

To install hbase I followed this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_installation.htm) in which they say we can check the hbase instance on the webUI on the address addressOfMyMachine:60010, I also checked on the port 16010 but this is not working.
I have an error saying this:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
> Please try again later.
>
> If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.

I managed to run the hbase shell but I don't know if my installation is working well.

Comment: Run a `list` command in `hbase shell`.

Comment: I did, I had the TABLE displayed and now the webui is working but I don't really know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if Hbase is running or not using shell script, execute the command below.

```
if echo -e "list" | hbase shell 2>&1 | grep -q "ERROR:" 2>/dev/null ;then echo "Hbase is not running"; fi
```